# Flask-JSGlue doesn't provide Flask object to JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm using [Flask-JSGlue](https://stewartpark.github.io/Flask-JSGlue/), which is supposed to provide a `Flask` object with methods like `url_for` in JavaScript. I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Flask is not defined` in `scripts.js`. Why am I getting this error?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_jsglue import JSGlue

app = Flask(__name__)
JSGlue(app)

@app.route("/city")
def city():
    return render_template("city.html")
```

`scripts.js`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.pathname == '/city') {
        $.getJSON(Flask.url_for('city'), parameters).done(function (json_city, x, y) {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = json_city['background_filename'];
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[As the docs explain](https://stewartpark.github.io/Flask-JSGlue/#invoking-url-for-at-the-front-end-side), you need to include Flask-JSGlue's script on your rendered page. You need to include it *before* anything that depends on it.

```html
<head>
    {{ JSGlue.include() }}
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```